# C# - Saving and Loading data to file

Tags: c#, class, file-io

I decided to get into coding and am learning c#, after making a few small projects, I decided to step it up a little and make a text adventure game, with saving and loading, and if I get to feeling zany I'll try to add some multiplayer. While I haven't really hit a road block because of it, I can't help but feel that I am doing load function REALLY sub-optimally. The save is fine, I feel like it works for me, but the load I feel can be really simplified, I just don't know what to use.

I also wouldn't really mind, but with this way, if I add other attributes/skills or whatever else that needs to be saved, I will have to add everything to the load function as well, and it will be even longer.

I have tried to search around on here, the c# documentation, and other sites, but can't find a solution that works for this case. can anyone help me find a better way of doing this? Or is this the best I can really do since it's varying data types?

Edit: To simplify and clarify what answer I am searching for, I am trying to find a simpler and more scalable way to save and load the data to a file.

```
        static void LoadGame(CharData PlayerData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the character to load as shown below.");
        //getting current directory info, setting to di
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        //need to initialize these outside of a loop
        int SaveFiles = 0;
        string DisplayName = " ";
        int DisplayNameLength = 0;
        //looks through files in working directory ending in '.fasv', displays them in format '{x}. John Smith'
        foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles("*.fasv"))
        {
            SaveFiles++;
            DisplayNameLength = fi.Name.Length;
            //remove .fasv from displayed name to make it look nicer
            DisplayName = fi.Name.Remove(DisplayNameLength - 5, 5);
            Console.WriteLine(SaveFiles.ToString() + ". " + DisplayName);
        }
        string toLoad = Console.ReadLine();
        using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(toLoad + ".fasv");
        //the name is easy to get since it's a string. but integers...
        PlayerData.Name = sr.ReadLine();
        //... not so much. i hate all of this and i feel like it's gross, but i don't know how else to do it
        int hp, xp, level, toughness, innovation, mind, empathy, spryness;
        Int32.TryParse(sr.ReadLine(), out hp);
        Int32.TryParse(sr.ReadLine(), out xp);
        Int32.TryParse(sr.ReadLine(), out level);
        Int32.TryParse(sr.ReadLine(), out toughness);
        Int32.TryParse(sr.ReadLine(), out innovation);
        Int32.TryParse(sr.ReadLine(), out mind);
        Int32.TryParse(sr.ReadLine(), out empathy);
        Int32.TryParse(sr.ReadLine(), out spryness);
        PlayerData.Health = hp;
        PlayerData.Level = level;
        PlayerData.XP = xp;
        PlayerData.Toughness = toughness;
        PlayerData.Innovation = innovation;
        PlayerData.Mind = mind;
        PlayerData.Empathy = empathy;
        PlayerData.Spryness = spryness;
        sr.Close();
        InGame(PlayerData);
    }



    static void SaveGame(CharData PlayerData)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(PlayerData.Name + ".fasv"))
        {
            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo stat in PlayerData.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                //write player data properties to file line by line, using stat to iterate through the player data properties
                sw.WriteLine(stat.GetValue(PlayerData));
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] question to clarify what exactly you trying to learn with this code. (Obviously you are not interested in just save/load data to JSON or XML)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't set on a particular data format for the file data, I would recommend using a serializer such as JSON.NET. You can use NuGet to add newtonsoft.json to your project, and that would allow you to just do something similar to:

```cs
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(pathToPlayerFile))
{
  var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
  serializer.Serialize(file, playerData);
}
```

And then your code to read from the file would be pretty similar:

```cs
using (var file = File.OpenText(pathToPlayerFile))
{
  var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
  return (CharData)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(CharData));
}
```

I borrowed those code snippets from newtonsoft.com. `CreateText` will create (or overwrite) the file and write the object as a JSON object.

Comment: This looks very promising and a lot better than I had come up with! I will test it and mark it as the answer if all works well :)

Comment: I'm glad it looks promising. It will format it like { "FirstName": "Andy", "LastName": "Merts", ... } which is probably significantly different than what you have. Worst case though, you could update your Save method first and use your existing Load function. That would let you convert your existing user record. Typically you would name files saved in this format with a "json" extension.

Comment: Yea the formatting doesn't really matter much to me, I'll work around whatever the serializer gives me. Neither does the file extension, I just made one up that wasn't used by anything I know of, a .json file is fine for me

Comment: Yep, this works amazingly for me! Thank you so much for mentioning NuGet, because the main reason I wasn't already using a serializer because I didn't know what I needed to do to enable the use of one lol